# Disconnect Specific Network Sessions

Tags: session, vbscript, hta, mapped-drive

I'm busy making an HTA applet, which authenticates my users' sessions as they log on to their workstation. Ideally, I'd like to be able to terminate an active network session, instead of just removing the network drives which are made when users are authenticated.

I've only learned of HTA three days ago, which may be why I'm struggling a bit, and my VBS knowledge isn't all that good either, so I'm working off examples of code by stitching them together. The HTA method seems to be the most simple and suitable method of accomplishing what I wanted to do, as I'm able to map drives without any apparent difficulty.

Can someone take a look at my script, and tell me how I can **optimise it to accomplish what I'm trying to do**? I'm learning every step of the way, so please guide me to the appropraite solution (I'd like to try it myself first).

---

**Objective:**

Be able to remove a currently active network session from only a specific server when the HTA is launched by the user.

**Issues and Occurrences:**

*Assuming Correct Credentials*: The credentials are pulled to the Sub called "ExecMapping", and is validated by the script to be a valid length (no blanks).

1. The script runs completely through the ExecMapping Sub, which checks if there are any errors in attempting to create a new mapping. If multiple mapping exists, error dialog is thrown for that specific mapping.
2. Most often than not, I get a "Multiple Connections" error, as expected. This is what should be resolved.

[image: Multiple Connection Error]

**The Scripting:**

```
<HEAD>
<!-- Full Credits to the Authors of the ReadIni Function

     Dependencies:
     -> Logo (./Logo_alpha.png)
     -> Ini File (./config.ini)
     -> Icon (./Kreede$arch$.ico)
-->
<TITLE>Kreede Authenticator</TITLE>

<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Kreede Authenticator"
  VERSION="1.2"
  BORDER="none"
  INNERBORDER="no"
  CAPTION="no"
  SYSMENU="no"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  ICON="Kreede32.ico"
  SCROLL="no"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
  CONTEXTMENU="no"
  SELECTION="no"/>
</HEAD>

<SCRIPT language="vbscript">

Function ReadIni( myFilePath, mySection, myKey )
    ' This function returns a value read from an INI file
    '
    ' Arguments:
    ' myFilePath  [string]  the (path and) file name of the INI file
    ' mySection   [string]  the section in the INI file to be searched
    ' myKey       [string]  the key whose value is to be returned
    '
    ' Returns:
    ' the [string] value for the specified key in the specified section
    '
    ' CAVEAT:     Will return a space if key exists but value is blank
    '
    ' Written by Keith Lacelle
    ' Modified by Denis St-Pierre and Rob van der Woude

    Const ForReading   = 1
    Const ForWriting   = 2
    Const ForAppending = 8

    Dim intEqualPos
    Dim objFSO, objIniFile
    Dim strFilePath, strKey, strLeftString, strLine, strSection

    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

    ReadIni     = ""
    strFilePath = Trim( myFilePath )
    strSection  = Trim( mySection )
    strKey      = Trim( myKey )

    If objFSO.FileExists( strFilePath ) Then
        Set objIniFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( strFilePath, ForReading, False )
        Do While objIniFile.AtEndOfStream = False
            strLine = Trim( objIniFile.ReadLine )

            ' Check if section is found in the current line
            If LCase( strLine ) = "[" & LCase( strSection ) & "]" Then
                strLine = Trim( objIniFile.ReadLine )

                ' Parse lines until the next section is reached
                Do While Left( strLine, 1 ) <> "["
                    ' Find position of equal sign in the line
                    intEqualPos = InStr( 1, strLine, "=", 1 )
                    If intEqualPos > 0 Then
                        strLeftString = Trim( Left( strLine, intEqualPos - 1 ) )
                        ' Check if item is found in the current line
                        If LCase( strLeftString ) = LCase( strKey ) Then
                            ReadIni = Trim( Mid( strLine, intEqualPos + 1 ) )
                            ' In case the item exists but value is blank
                            If ReadIni = "" Then
                                ReadIni = " "
                            End If
                            ' Abort loop when item is found
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    End If

                    ' Abort if the end of the INI file is reached
                    If objIniFile.AtEndOfStream Then Exit Do

                    ' Continue with next line
                    strLine = Trim( objIniFile.ReadLine )
                Loop
            Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        objIniFile.Close
    Else
        WScript.Echo strFilePath & " doesn't exists. Exiting..."
        Wscript.Quit 1
    End If
End Function

Sub Window_onLoad
    Dim objNetwork
    Dim objFSO
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

    '### First Impressions! ###
    window.resizeTo 480,270
    window.moveTo screen.width / 3, screen.height / 4

    '### Remove Previous Session's Access to Shared Drives ###
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.DriveExists("O") Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive("O:")
    End If
    If objFSO.DriveExists("S") Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive("S:")
    End If
    Set objNetwork = Nothing

End Sub

Sub CancelAction

    '### Remove Previous Session's Access to Shared Drives ###
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.DriveExists("O") Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive("O:")
    End If
    If objFSO.DriveExists("S") Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive("S:")
    End If

    MsgBox "You have not logged in, and will not be able to access drives O: and S: To regain access, please run Kreede from your Desktop again.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Important"
    Set oShell = Nothing
    Set objNetwork = Nothing
    Self.Close()

End Sub

Sub ExecMapping
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim objNetwork, oShell, WshShell

    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    '### Initialise all variables needed ###
    strDriveLetter1 = "O:"
    strDriveLetter2 = "S:"
    '### Our Fail-Safe Locations, just in case... ###
    strRemotePath1 = "\\172.16.18.3\corporate"
    strRemotePath2 = "\\172.16.18.3\scratch"
    strDriveAlias1 = "Corporate (HO)"
    strDriveAlias2 = "Scratch (HO)"
    intTimeout = 1 'Seconds
    strMessage = "Login Succeeded!"
    strTitle = "Success!"

    '### We'll find out who you are in bit, but we first need to know where you are? ###
    strBranch = UCase(ReadIni(".\config.ini", "Config-Data", "branch"))

    Select Case strBranch
        Case "HO"
            strRemotePath1 = "\\172.16.18.3\corporate"
            strRemotePath2 = "\\172.16.18.3\scratch"
            strDriveAlias1 = "Corporate (HO)"
            strDriveAlias2 = "Scratch (HO)"
        Case "REM"
            strRemotePath1 = "\\172.16.20.3\corporate"
            strRemotePath2 = "\\172.16.20.3\scratch"
            strDriveAlias1 = "Office (Remote)"
            strDriveAlias2 = "Scratch (Remote)"
    End Select

    '### Are we working with humans? Set minimum length for validation ###
    validUsr = 2
    validPass = 3

    '### Check if the Computer lied... ###
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.DriveExists("O") Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive("O:")
    End If
    If objFSO.DriveExists("S") Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive("S:")
    End If

    '### Map drives using the entered credentials ###

    'STEP 1: Collect Credentials
    strUser = TextBox1.Value
    strPwd = TextBox2.Value

    'STEP 2: Validate and Map!
    If Len(strUser) >= validUser Then
        strUsr = Ucase(strUser)

        If Len(strPwd) >= validPass Then
            Err.Clear

            objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter1, strRemotePath1, False, strUser, strPwd
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "MAP-O :: Error Occurred [" & Err.Number & "]: " & Err.Description               
            End If

            objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter2, strRemotePath2, False, strUser, strPwd
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "MAP-S :: Error Occurred [" & Err.Number & "]: " & Err.Description       
                Call CancelAction       
            End If

            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                oShell.NameSpace(strDriveLetter1).Self.Name = strDriveAlias1
                oShell.NameSpace(strDriveLetter2).Self.Name = strDriveAlias2
                intResult = WshShell.Popup(strMessage, intTimeout, strTitle)
            End If

        Else
            Msgbox "Password is invalid!"
            Exit Sub        
        End If

    ELSE
        Msgbox chr(34) & strUser & """ is not a valid username!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set oShell = Nothing
    Set objNetwork = Nothing
    Self.Close()

End Sub


</SCRIPT>


<BODY STYLE="
    TEXT-ALIGN: center; 
    background-color: #dddddd; 
    FONT:10 pt verdana; 
    COLOR:black; 
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#FFCC66', EndColorStr='#FFFFFF')
    ">

<img src="./Logo_alpha.png" alt="Logo"></a><br>
Please enter your corporate user credentials to access the Corporate Servers.<br><br>
<CENTER>
<HR color="#FF0000">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><font size="2" color="black" face="Arial">
    <tr>
        <td height="30">
            <p align="right">Username</p>
        </td>
        <td height="30">&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="TextBox1" size="30">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30">
            <p align="right">Password</p>
        </td>
        <td height="30">&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="password" name="TextBox2" size="30">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<HR color="#FF0000">
<Input id=runbutton class="button" type="button" value="  Login  " name="run_button" onClick="ExecMapping">

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<Input id=runbutton class="button" type="button" value="Cancel" name="cancel_button" onClick="CancelAction"><br>
<span style="font-size: 8pt; color: red"><strong>If you cancel, you will not be able to access the O: and S: drives in this session.</strong></span>
</CENTER>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may either use the below command line to remove ALL connections, or first iterate through the current connections and disconnect what matching your criteria.

```
net use * /delete /yes
```

Or, do a **objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives** then **objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive** for each of that.

** Note:  For those connection which is mapped with a local drive letter, you will need to do something like objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive("\172.16.18.3\corporate")

Good luck.